# assigning structure arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, structure

Hi i have the following 3 functions that are in different m. files  in the same folder:

The first two functions (sum and mult) are for summing and multiplying elements respectively:

```
function sum =  sum_elements()

a = 1;
sum = 0;
for i = 1:5
    sum = sum + a;
end
return


function mult =  mult_elements()

b = 2;
mult = 1;
for i = 1:5
    mult = mult * b;
end
return
```

In the third function i want to use structures for perform summing and multiplying tasks and storing them in a variable "calc":

```
function calc_sum_mult(a,b,sum,mult)

I = 5;

for i = 1:I
    calc(i).sum = sum_elements()
    calc(i).mult = mult_elements()
end
```

But when i run the 3rd function i get and error " not enough input argument"

Any help???

Comment: *Please*, do not use `sum` as a variable name. If you get used to using such names, your code will be crap and you will most likely eventually be eaten by a bear... (One bad thing leads to another...)

Comment: @RobertP. Or physically assaulted by a TA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `calc(i).sum = sum()` to `calc(i).sum = sum_elements()`, and `calc(i).mult = mult()` to `calc(i).mult = mult_elements()`. Functions are called by its name, not by the name of the output argument used in its definition.

In your code as it stands, `sum` is a Matlab bulitin function that can't be called without input elements. That's why you get the error.